# Could not create the DataSource when starting a node using the finance cordapp on Corda 4.0 [errorCode=13ajh5q]

Tags: corda

When starting up a Corda Node using the Open Source 4.0 version, using the example finance cordapp the node fails with this error:

```
   ______               __
  / ____/     _________/ /___ _
 / /     __  / ___/ __  / __ `/         Where do cryptographers go for
/ /___  /_/ / /  / /_/ / /_/ /          entertainment? The security theatre.
\____/     /_/   \__,_/\__,_/

--- Corda Open Source 4.0 (503a2ff) -------------------------------------------------------------


Logs can be found in                    : C:\git\samples\obligation-cordapp\kotlin-source\build\nodes\PartyA\logs
[quasar] WARNING: Method not found in class - assuming suspendable: net/corda/finance/workflows/GetBalances#getCashBalance(Lnet/corda/core/node/ServiceHub;Ljava/util/Currency;)Lnet/corda/core/contracts/Amount; (at SettleObligation.kt:net/corda/examples/obligation/flows/SettleObligation$Initiator#call)
[quasar] WARNING: Method not found in class - assuming suspendable: net/corda/finance/workflows/asset/CashUtils#generateSpend$default(Lnet/corda/core/node/ServiceHub;Lnet/corda/core/transactions/TransactionBuilder;Ljava/util/List;Lnet/corda/core/identity/PartyAndCertificate;Ljava/util/Set;ILjava/lang/Object;)Lkotlin/Pair; (at SettleObligation.kt:net/corda/examples/obligation/flows/SettleObligation$Initiator#call)
! ATTENTION: This node is running in development mode!  This is not safe for production deployment.
[ERROR] 11:55:02+0000 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Could not create the DataSource: Error parsing master.changelog.json: Could not create the DataSource: Error parsing master.changelog.json [errorCode=13ajh5q, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0/13ajh5q]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Corda 4.0 the finance cordapp has been split into two parts, corda-finance-contracts and corda-finance-workflows.

Due to the work on signature contraints, (See here: https://docs.corda.net/release-notes.html#signature-constraints), CorDapp JARs can now be signed. As a result we recommend creating seperate JARs for contracts and workflows so workflows can evolve seperately to the contracts they depend on.

The corda-workflows-finance JAR contains the database migrations for the finance app, so you need both apps installed for the finance app to work. Adding the workflows JAR to the nodes cordapp directory will fix the issue.

The JAR is available here: https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/corda-finance-workflows/

Comment: I have build my cordapp and created liquibase scripts based on the tutorial but getting following error message "[ERROR] 2019-11-20T07:00:22,843Z [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Could not create the DataSource: Error parsing master.changelog.json: Could not create the DataSource: Error parsing master.changelog.json [errorCode=13ajh5q, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/ENT/4.0/13ajh5q] {}" I tried placing the migration folder under resources or build/nodes but error says the changelog.master does not exist. I am using corda ent 4.0